# Start Monitoring Built-in Event Endpoint

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-hub

I was given the iothubower SharedAccessKey for an IoT Hub instance I don't have otherwise access.

Using Visual Studio Code I can **Set IoT Hub Connection String** using the iothubowner credentials and then **Create Device** to create a device on the IoT Hub.

[image]

However, when I try to **Start Monitoring Built-in Event Endpoint** on that device, I am asked for additional information, namely the **Event Hub compatible connection string**.

[image]

Is this string something I can retrieve using the iothubowner credentials that I've been given? I don't have access to the Azure Portal.
I see the structure of the **Event Hub compatible connection string** consists of a namespace (which I don't know) and the event hub name, in addition to the iothubowner credentials.

Is the namespace and event hub name something I can retrieve using the my credentials?
Is there any other way I can monitor events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Hub compatible endpoint with iothubowner credentials in my case looks something like this:

```
Endpoint=sb://iothub-ns-{part_of_iot_hub_name}-2052657-6507c44fda.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={shared_access_key}=;EntityPath={iot_hub_name}
```

The namespace looks like this and is not a part of iothubowner credentials(connection string):

```
iothub-ns-{part_of_iot_hub_name}-2052657-6507c44fda
```

As you can see, this endpoint cuts the IoT hub name and contains some numbers - which would be really hard to guess. So if you have the namespace, you can construct the endpoint, otherwise, I would say no and you need access to the Azure portal or to log in with 'az command' and retrieve it with Powershell.

Comment: I also tried to get the endpoint via an az command but could not find any that accepts the iothubowner credential on the command line

Comment: no, you need azure credentials. iothubowner just provides some permission to perform some IoT Hub operations in this case like, create new device identity, send direct method, C2D message etc. So is required for Service SDK to work properly, but not beyond that.

Comment: Thank you, I accept the answer. Older versions of Visual Studio Code did not require this endpoint connection string, neither did the old Device Explorer Twin

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an accepted answer, I could not quite figure out how to get my Endpoint.

You need to go to your IoT Hub and click on "Built-in endpoints" and there you will find the Entry:

[image]